# Why are Python packges installed in such a convoluted path and is this a problem

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I just installed Jupyter Lab and I got this warning about the PATH.  This directory is very messy - C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\Scripts.  Why such a long path and is this going to cause problems due to limits in the number of characters in a path name

And should I be adding this directory to the path?

```
  WARNING: The scripts jlpm.exe, jupyter-lab.exe, jupyter-labextension.exe and jupyter-labhub.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Installed Jupyter Labs in Windows 10

Comment: (1) because the first half of that path is the universal Windows location for application-specific data and the second half is "what python picked when you installed it", and (2) yes, respectively.

Comment: You're well under path length limits there. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: But why does Python use  PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311 rather than Python\Python311 or just Python311.  God forbid I ever have to type in the full path.

Comment: Because that's how whoever packaged your Python installation for Windows chose to configure the [installation paths and prefix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html#installation-paths). I agree they're pretty ugly, and I don't know the reasoning. Use Linux if you want sane paths.

Comment: @wim,  why blame the operating system for "sane" paths when they are selected by the user ?  this is not a standard windows install path...

Comment: The user certainly didn't ask for nonsense like PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0 in their installation path, that is something from an upstream packager for Windows. Maybe it was configurable by user at installation time in the Windows installer, I don't know, I imagine most people just click "next" through those installer wizards and accept the defaults.

Comment: @D.L I must admit I never saw such mess in Linux paths (unless it's something like `mktemp` directory that includes random characters in temporary directory name), and CamelCaseTryToTypeMe directory names are also much less frequent there. So there is some OS-dependent component which Windows doesn't get right - probably because it assumes that people shouldn't need terminal and prefer to find nested preferences in terribly-looking ui supplements.

Comment: the standard (default) installation path in windows is here: `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`. The path in the question is from a custom install...

Comment: @D.L: It’s the Windows Store install location.

Comment: @Ry- What is the meaning of qbz5n2kfra8p0? Is that some sort of checksum?

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments (including my own). The reason for the long path name is due to the *user selection at the time of installation*.

It was suggested in the final comment (by @Ry-) that this particular installation is the **windows store install** default path.

I have always installed directly from the official https://www.python.org website which offers a one click installation and the default path there is `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`, which is much more concise.